# How do I go back to the menu after taking several questions?

Tags: java, loops

I am currently creating a program where the user enters a specific set of questions. And the program must go back to the menu after completely answering all questions. How should I do it?

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("""
                \n \nAre you ready to take the quiz?
                Enter "Y" to proceed or "N" to exit the program:""");

        String TakeQuiz = input.nextLine();

        if (TakeQuiz.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
            do {
            //blocks of code

                    }
                }
            }

                System.out.println("Do you want to take the quiz again?");
                String RetakeQuiz = input.nextLine();
                while (RetakeQuiz.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) ;
            

        else {
            System.out.println("We hope to see you again soon!");
            System.exit(0);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You already seem to be using a loop so what's the problem? One side not though: stick to the Java code conventions to reduce confusion. `TakeQuiz` and `RetakeQuiz` look very much like class names and that can cause hard to spot or understand bugs (maybe not in your case but it's good to cultivate a good habit early on)

Answer (score 0):

The basic structure is something like this:

```
boolean continueWithQuiz = true;

while (continueWithQuiz) {
    // Put the code here for handling the quiz
       ...
    // Should we keep going?
    System.out.println("Do you want to take the quiz again?");
    String retakeQuiz = input.nextLine();
    continueWithQuiz = retakeQuiz == "Y";
}
```

One more comment. Please follow Java naming standards. Class names begin with an upper case letter. Constants should be ALL_CAPS. Everything else is in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you want, I would not clutter the main method and break the code to another function and loop there.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(;;)
            takeQuiz();
    }

    public static void takeQuiz(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\n \nAre you ready to take the quiz?" +
                "Enter \"Y\" to proceed or \"N\" to exit the program:");

        String takeQuiz = input.nextLine();

        if (takeQuiz.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {

            System.out.println("Running code...");
            System.out.println("Question 1");
            System.out.println("Question 2");
            System.out.println("Question 3");
        }

        // retake
        if (takeQuiz.equalsIgnoreCase("R")){
            takeQuiz();
        }
        if (takeQuiz.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
            System.out.println("We hope to see you again soon!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

*Notice the escape character for quotes \" and the + for multiline Strings*

- Java 15 and beyond allows triple quotes as [Java Text Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/text-blocks/index.html)
  so your String message should be valid